# How to set BPG on background

Tags: javascript, html, css, background-image, bpg

Can I use a [BPG](http://bellard.org/bpg/) image as a `<div>` or `<body>` background? `background: url('bg.bpg');` doesn't work.

There is a Javascript decoder which allows .bpg images to be displayed in `<img>` tags, but I want to use one as a `<body>` background.

Comment: ...in which browser? More to the point, do *any* browsers support .bpg files at the moment?

Comment: But there is a javascript decoder which allows to display bpg.

Comment: I'd mention that in your question, then - it could be that the script isn't being loaded, or an error elsewhere is preventing the Javascript from running, or there could be a bug in the Javascript code, or it could be something browser-specific. Please add as much information as possible!

Comment: I am using standard example from http://bellard.org/bpg/, it displays images properly, but I wouldn't display img but set img like a body background

Comment: Please edit your question to include this information, rather than adding it in the comments - It helps more people to notice it.

Answer (score 12):

The Javascript BPG decoder works by converting the source .bpg file into an [`ImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object, which can then be drawn to a canvas. So all you need to do is [get the canvas as a PNG data string](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement.toDataURL) and set that as the body background image:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>BPG background example.</title>
        <!-- Decoder script from http://bellard.org/bpg/ -->
        <script src="bpgdec8a.js"></script>
        <script>
"use strict";

function setBackground(filename)
{

  // Create a hidden canvas with the same dimensions as the image.
  var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  canvas.style.visibility = "hidden";
  canvas.width = 512;
  canvas.height = 512;
  document.body.appendChild(canvas);

  // Create a drawing context and a BPG decoder.
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var img = new BPGDecoder(ctx);

  // Attempt to load the image.
  img.onload = function()
  {
    // Once the image is ready, draw it to the canvas...
    ctx.putImageData(this.imageData, 0, 0);
    // ...and copy the canvas to the body background.
    document.body.style.background = "url('" + canvas.toDataURL("image/png") + "')";
  };
  img.load(filename);

}
        </script>
    </head>
    <body onload="setBackground('lena512color.bpg');">
        <p>Hello, World!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```